# Jenkins REST API: Obtaining the coverage report

Tags: rest, jenkins, jacoco

I am working on a Jenkins REST API consumer application. I am looking for a way to grab the JaCoCo code coverage report (a link to the code coverage report page) from Jenkins using the REST API. It appears that JaCoCo plugin for Jenkins doesn't expose any information over REST. Could anyone suggest how can we get this information over REST ? Or any other options ?

Thanks,

Aravind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get Jacoco Code Coverage report by calling

https:///view/test/job//lastSuccessfulBuild/jacoco/api/xml.

This will give u code coverage report in xml format and from there you can get what ever you want.

Thanks